# how can i import blog xml file into wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have downloaded my blogger xml file several years before .Nowadays,people can not serf on blogger in china,it is banned by gfw.how  can i import the blogger xml file into my wordpress?
Please do not tell me the way to click the “Authorize” button in wordpress to enter my blogger,people can not link blogger anymore.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content#Blogger

Answer (score 0):

go to Tools → Import → Blogger.

also check this [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content#Google_Blog_Converters)

Comment: when you do as that way, a window will popup to let you to Authorize to link the blogger ,when you click  Authorize ,wa,you will be blocked by great GFW.

Comment: The only wat is to parse it i can think myself,to extract every title and the content in the title.

Comment: what i say will happen in china ,will not happen in most other countries.blogger was blocked by government here.